# Python List Loops, Print Satellite Names according to Number Enetered after Comma

Tags: python, list, loops

UserInput: (“LANDSAT8,5,MODIS,3,SENTINAL2,6”).
User entered three satellites name and instruct the program that how many images of that
particular satellite should be downloaded. In this example, there are three pairs;

1. LANDSAT8,5
2. MODIS,3
3. SENTINAL2,6

Preferred Output should be like:

Program Output:
LANDSAT8 image 1 downloaded
LANDSAT8 image 2 downloaded
LANDSAT8 image 3 downloaded
LANDSAT8 image 4 downloaded
LANDSAT8 image 5 downloaded
MODIS image 1 downloaded
MODIS image 2 downloaded
MODIS image 3 downloaded
SENTINAL2 image 1 downloaded
SENTINAL2 image 2 downloaded
SENTINAL2 image 3 downloaded
SENTINAL2 image 4 downloaded
SENTINAL2 image 5 downloaded
SENTINAL2 image 6 downloaded

Comment: So, what is your question? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be what you're trying to do:

```
user_input = "LANDSAT8,5,MODIS,3,SENTINAL2,6"

tokens = user_input.split(',')

for s, d in zip(tokens[::2], map(int, tokens[1::2])):
    for i in range(d):
        print(f'{s} image {i+1} downloaded')
```

**Output:**

```
LANDSAT8 image 1 downloaded
LANDSAT8 image 2 downloaded
LANDSAT8 image 3 downloaded
LANDSAT8 image 4 downloaded
LANDSAT8 image 5 downloaded
MODIS image 1 downloaded
MODIS image 2 downloaded
MODIS image 3 downloaded
SENTINAL2 image 1 downloaded
SENTINAL2 image 2 downloaded
SENTINAL2 image 3 downloaded
SENTINAL2 image 4 downloaded
SENTINAL2 image 5 downloaded
SENTINAL2 image 6 downloaded
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UserInput="LANDSAT8,5,MODIS,3,SENTINAL2,6"
numbers=[]
names=[]
for keyword in UserInput.split(","):
    if keyword.isdigit():
        numbers.append(keyword)
    else:
        names.append(keyword)

for i in range(len(names)):
    temp=numbers[i]
    for j in range(int(temp)):
        print(names[i],"image "+str(j)+" downloaded",end=" ")
```

Comment: Thank You Adan, It worked out perfectly with a little addition.

Comment: UserInput=input("Enter Satellite Name,Enter Number")
numbers=[] 
names=[] 
for keyword in UserInput.split(","): 
  if keyword.isdigit(): 
   numbers.append(keyword)
  else: 
   names.append(keyword) 
for i in range(len(names)): 
  temp=numbers[i]
  for j in range(int(temp)): 
      print(names[i],"image "+str(j)+" downloaded",end="\n")

Comment: @SheharyarBhatti That's nice to hear it worked well for you, cheers:)

Answer (score 0):

## Overview

you need to get input, split the input on a `,` comma, and then zip them into pairs, then generate your output text and then you can print or do whatever you want with the output array, each element in the output array is a string. using
`{x} image {y} downloaded` as the format

## Code

```py
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0, s1), (s2, s3), (s4, s5), ..."
    a = iter(iterable)
    return zip(a, a)

user_input = input("enter satelites: ")

splitted = user_input.split(',')

output = []
for x, y in pairwise(splitted):
    output.append(f"{x} image {y} downloaded");

for x in output: # Do your downloading stuff 
    print(x)
```

## Output (usage)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
inp = input()

words = inp.split(sep=",")

satellites = {}
i = 0
while i < len(words):
    satellites[words[i]] = int(words[i + 1])
    i += 2

for key, value in satellites.items():
    for i in range(1, value + 1):
        print(f"{key} image {i} downloaded")
```

Comment: Thanks alot for answering, but there is a little thing more. The out put should contain messages printed equal to what the user writes after comma. Such as Landsat8,5 - out put  should be 5 lines written Landsat8 image 0 downloaded, Landsat8 image 1 downloaded...so on. Upto "5" Times since written after comma is "5".

Comment: Are u actuallying downloading something or just printing the output?

Comment: Im just printing out put..